# Do Star Trek characters wearing red shirts have the highest death rate on the original show?

Tags: character, star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

In many episodes of the original series of *Star Trek* ([*Star Trek TOS*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060028/)) a team will be selected to beam down to the planet (or wherever the action was in the episode). This will have major characters from the series (like Bones, Kirk or Spock) who are (obviously) going to survive whatever adventure awaits. But the team will also have minor characters. Sometimes some of them will die.

It has been a widely shared belief that the minor characters wearing red shirts are the ones most likely to die. Is this really true (especially if adjusted for the number on the ship)?

PS if true, does this tendency extend to the later series after the original three *TOS* seasons?

Comment: you noticed that too. I always thought that was unfair. I think that has changed in the reboot.... The captain seems to take a lot of beatings.

Comment: For the record, if doing a Star Trek themed skit, having a red shirt die is obligatory.

Comment: According to [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedShirt), " [the] number of casualties that the Enterprise had, [...] compare[d] that to an actual military, [...] is excellent, [Kirk did] far better than any general in U.S. history"

Comment: @jpaugh but those are not naval in nature. You can't compare a navy captain to a army general for death rates

Comment: Also the black guy dies first in horror movies.

Comment: @cde Nothing about Star Trek is naval in nature... If anything, their death rates should have been much higher *where no man has gone before.*

Comment: @jpaugh space ship sci-fi is an extension of submarine and boat fiction, using the same tropes and common themes. Everything on Star Trek (except for 60% of DS9 naturally), is very much Navy oriented. Hell, look at TNG's high seas obsession.

Comment: @cde I get that, but... in terms of casualties, there's no realistic expectation that it would be low. Then again, there's no realistic expectation that it would be high, either.... *shrug*

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Red shirts have a skewed death rate in TOS due to the nature of their job. The Security role is handled by Ops, which all wear red shirts (Scotty, the engineer, is also Ops). So red shirts die in higher number because Security officers are at a higher risk. They assume guard duties and the dangers inherent to that role.

In TNG and beyond, the color structure has changed. Command has become the red shirts, and ops has become gold. In TNG, there is a higher number of gold shirt deaths. Tasha Yar being a prime example. Again,  it is because Security is gold.

> That’s according to Matthew Barsalou, who debunked the red shirt curse for Significance Magazine by mathematically breaking down the death rates, by uniform color, of characters on the original Star Trek. A simple pie chart reveals 55 total deaths and, yes, red shirts perished in frightening numbers. A whopping 24 died, compared to 9 in yellow/gold command and 7 in blue, with 15 crossing into the final frontier in unidentified colors. However, it’s all a matter of perspective and percentages. There were 430 crewmen aboard the Enterprise, 239 of them in engineering, security or operations, and all wore red. So, in reality, they had a decent survival rate, and it was, statistically speaking – courtesy of a little something called Bayes’ theorem -- the folks in gold who were more likely to meet their maker. - See more at: http://www.startrek.com/article/did-redshirts-really-die-more-often-on-tos#sthash.wUlkpts5.dpuf

So while red shirts in TOS are statistically safer, based on ship crew complement, they suffer a higher on screen death count. Higher number, lower percentage.

Comment: I like it: actual statistics and a proper explanation!

Comment: I think it would be better to link directly to Matthew Barsalou's original article in Significance Magazine. The link the StarTrek.com article gives is dead, but you can find it [here](https://www.statslife.org.uk/culture/458-keep-your-redshirt-on-star-trek-a-bayesian-exploration).

Comment: I dispute that it is due to the nature of their job. It seems more like terrible training and abnormally dreadful protocols. Many of those deaths were completely unavoidable. :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Their equipment is more terrible than their training, really - the only ones who can use it reliably are those who are *way* overtrained. This especially true in TNG. But even then, note that we *only* see the interesting stories. There might have been four hundred routine missions for each one we've seen on TV. But yes, TOS commonly used red-shirt "accidents" to warn the main characters of danger. Just a bit of lazy writing :P

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Did you mean to say that the deaths were avoidable? If they were unavoidable it would be pointless to try to blame training or protocols since unavoidable deaths would happen no matter how good they were.

Comment: @Glen_b Aw, you know what he meant, irregardless of his wording...

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Even if the Star-Trek characters were fantastically skilled (rather than under-skilled), they were still fantastically *lucky*: Virtually any real-life general would have had [a far worse casualty rate](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedShirt).

Comment: I'm not sure how these numbers "debunk" anything.  Ignoring the 15 unidentified, we have 24/239 (10%) deaths for red shirts, 16/201 (8%) for blue/gold combined.  That means the death rate for red shirts is a quarter higher than the aggregate of the other two colors.

Comment: What about those guys in the 1920s Football helmets?  http://starfleet1701st.yuku.com/reply/22060/Re-Starfleet-Security-Armour#.WPZ8-7pFz1s

Comment: @Monty https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: @cde well sure if your just going to make up stuff.

Comment: @coteyr it's a tv show, it's all made up

Comment: Is the ship's complement canon?  If we are going to count characters we don't actually see in calculating death rates, shouldn't we also count deaths we don't actually see?

Comment: FWIW, last week in a [talk at the Museum of Mathematics in New York](http://nerdist.com/star-trek-red-shirts-werent-statistically-the-most-likely-to-die-after-all/) James Grime also argued that when you combine on-screen death rates with data on the ships complement in the *Star Fleet Technical Manual*, Gold Shirts were actually statistically more like to die in STTOS.

Comment: Another recent analysis sort of agrees with this one. It was done by mathematician [James Grime](http://www.space.com/36450-star-trek-math-of-khan.html).

Comment: @eipi10 sorry,I posted without checking other comments: we have the same source!