# What is the significance of different color uniforms in Star Trek reboot series?

Tags: analysis, star-trek

What does the different color of uniform shirts signify in the Star Trek movies of the reboot series? In *Star Trek Into Darkness* Kirk orders Chekov to wear a Redshirt in place of a Yellow one to work in place of Scotty. In the original series, the colors were a little different and also have some ambiguity but in the reboot series, there are only 3 colors used Red, Yellow, and Blue.

So what are the different colors of uniforms used in the Star Trek reboot series?

Comment: Divide people of rank, so they can easily be recognized. Also it'd help to similar level people to gather and work. Another reason could be division by rank, then divide power.
Command in gold, next in power is another color, and so on...

Comment: relevant on SciFi: [Meaning of uniform color in Star Trek Voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90283/20916)

Comment: @Memor-X or from the home site : [Is there any rationale for the different colours of uniforms on the different series of Star Trek?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72041/is-there-any-rationale-for-the-different-colours-of-uniforms-on-the-different-se)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All colors represent different jobs and service roles in a ship. The reboot series adapted colors from the original series.

Here is the list of what job each color represents.

> - **The command division wore gold shirts.** This includes Captain Kirk, Lieutenant Sulu, and Pavel Chekov.
> - **The science and medical staff wore blue shirts.** This includes Lieutenant Commander McCoy and Commander Spock.
> - **The engineering and communications division wore red shirts.** This included Chief Engineer Scotty and Communications Officer Uhura.
> - **The security division also wore red shirts.** You might know these people as the careless supporting characters that are immediately killed whenever the crew is confronted by a new enemy. We told you to avoid them.
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.sporcle.com/blog/2017/03/star-trek-uniform-colors/)</sub>

When Kirk asks Chekov to put on a red shirt, he made Chekov his new chief of Engineering division.

> KIRK: Mister Chekov. You've been shadowing Mister Scott. You are familiar with the engineering systems of this ship?
>
> CHEKOV: Affirmative, sir.
>
> KIRK: **Good. You're my new Chief. Go put on a red shirt.**

[Script Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/Extras/STintoD.html)

As indicated in the list of uniform colors, Chekov was asked to put on a red shirt.

Comment: [Red shirt dies first](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71854/do-star-trek-characters-wearing-red-shirts-have-the-highest-death-rate-on-the-or)